# impdp import fails with object already exists in oracle 10g?

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-10g

I exported the dump using `EXPDP` command. After exporting I dropped the user and the associated tablespaces by logging is as `/ AS SYSDBA.`

Then I re-created the User and the Tablespaces. Then I imported the dump using `IMPDP`. 
After importing I tried logging in with the re-created user and tried to query a table. And I got the following error.

```
ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 5 (block # 326667)

ORA-01110: data file 5: '/data01/test/TBS_MYTBS_01.dbf'

ORA-27091: unable to queue I/O

ORA-27072: File I/O error

Additional information: 4

Additional information: 326666
```

Machine Details : `Sun Solaris`
Oracle Version  : `Oracle10g`

Could someone help me in resolving the error?

Comment: Voted to migrate to DBA.STACKEXCHANGE where hopefully you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a serious error. What is writte in the alertlog file?
First thought is that the file is damaged.
How exactly did you drop the tablespace[s]?
how exactly did you perform the export?
how exactly did you re-create the tablespace[s]?
how exactly did you re-create the schema?
how exactly did you perform the import?
You should have dropped them using

```
drop tablespace X including contents and datafiles;
```

This would have taken care for cleanup of the old tablespaces. I also expect that you would have gotten errors during the import. When messing with databases and tablespaces, a little dba training would be very good. For 10g start here [Oracle® Database 2 Day DBA
10g Release 2 (10.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/toc.htm)

and yes, this is more a dba question and task than for a developer.